# What does it mean by "out of sight" here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

From *Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone*:

> "Three up... two across he muttered. "Right, stand back, Harry."
>
> He tapped the wall three times with the point of his umbrella.
>
> The brick he had touched quivered –– it wriggled –– in the middle, a small hole appeared –– it grew wider and wider –– a second later they were facing an archway large enough even for Hagrid, an archway onto a cobbled street that twisted and turned **out of sight.**
>
> "Welcome," said Hagrid, "to Diagon Alley."

'out of sight' means not visible, but here the cobbled street seems to be appearing in front of their eyes. And 'that' here refers to the street, doesnt it? Then how can the street be 'out of their sight' in this scene? I don't understand this sentence.

Comment: @P.E.Dant yes i've already seen that one. But I'm not asking the difference between twist and turn. I'm asking why 'out of sight' was used here cause i don't get it..

Comment: @P.E.Dant It was quite clear from the question that the OP's question was with the 'out of sight' part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you ever stood on a street/road that at some point turned until you could no longer see where it was going? That's what the sentence means. The cobbled street twisted and turned until Harry could no longer see where it was going and could not see its end.

Here's a good example of a road that 'twists out of sight': http://wallup.net/nature-landscape-trees-forest-grass-road-twist-2/

Comment: @P.E.Dant I explained the phrase with 'twisted and turned' because the problem the OP had was _obviously_ with the 'out of sight' part of the phrase.